# Getting "Could not cast literal "UTC" to type TIME" while running BigQuery SQL through CubeJS

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to query BigQuery from CubeJS. The `table` in BigQuery contains a column `START` with datatype as `DATE` (Ex., 2020-02-17, 1982-05-04, ...). The cube data model for  this column is -

```yaml
- name: start
  sql: START
  type: time
```

I am trying to make below query.

```sql
SELECT
  `table`.COLUMN2 `table__COLUMN2`,
  DATETIME_TRUNC(DATETIME(`table`.START, 'UTC'), DAY) `table__start_day`,
  count(*) `table__count`
FROM
  database.table AS `table`
GROUP BY
  1,
  2
ORDER BY
  2 ASC
LIMIT
  10000
```

When I run this query, I get this error - `Could not cast literal "UTC" to type TIME at [3:46]`.

Here's what I have tried-

- Tried to change the column data type to TIMESTAMP. However, since it contains date only, it cannot be converted to TIMESTAMP as conversion needs data to be in a particular format.
- Removing the "UTC" part from the query works just fine. But the query is being fired from Cube which I cannot control unless it's related to data model files.

Thanks :)